# How to Insert multiple rows of data into a table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am currently new to programming over all and I have all sorts of questions when it comes to PHP, but my first question is how to add multiple data to a table only using one variable. For example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'testpass', 'testdatabase')
or die (mysqli_error());

$test = "INSERT INTO test (test1, test2) VALUES ('test1', 'test2')";
$test .= "INSERT INTO test (test1, test2) VALUES ('test3', 'test4')";

if (!$test){
  echo "Sorry but you information could not be added...";
}
else {
  $test_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $test);
  echo "Your data has been entered!";
}
```

When I use this code when trying to add multiple data into my table it doesn't work. I can only add in 1 row at a time. I can never add in 2, 3, or more rows in at a time. Is there an error in my code? When I look at other example, people user mysql and not mysqli. The people using mysql use that same code as I have above. I prefer using mysqli and not having to switch because of something that is so small. Back to my question, how do I add multiple rows of data into a table? Thanks!

Comment: Try to add `;`after each MySQL command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert multiple rows use this:

```
INSERT INTO test (test1, test2) VALUES ('test1', 'test2'), ('test3', 'test4'), ('test5', 'test6')
```

which would insert 3 rows.